# Adding a new column in a dataframe based on multiple columns

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe. It is just the head and there are 17,568 rows. I want to add a new column called "average_no_of_steps" whose value will be equal to the average of all the steps corresponding to the interval in that row. So how can I do this?

```
     steps         date      interval 
1  37.3826   2012-10-01             0      
2  37.3826   2012-10-01             5      
3  37.3826   2012-10-01            10      
4  37.3826   2012-10-01            15          
5  37.3826   2012-10-01            20      
6  37.3826   2012-10-01             0
```

Comment: i used the ddply function but it is returning a dataframe with only average_no_of_steps   and interval column. I want the entire dataframe along with the new cloumn

Comment: Please add the piece of code you used in your question.

Comment: Create a new dataframe which will contain intervals and their averages.  Then `merge` this dataframe with your original on the interval.  Pascal will provide the code as I am burned out for the week :-(

Answer (score 0):

Lets make a sample data that replicates your example

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(steps=rnorm(1000, mean=35, sd=45), 
             interval=sample(c(0,5,10,15), 1000, replace=T))
```

Now, we will group by the variable you want to make the aggregate on and, finally, create the new column that will consider the previous groups to make the aggregation, leaving you with a data frame of the same dimensions.

```
df <- df %>% group_by(interval) %>%
mutate(mean=mean(steps))
```

Comment: Please include explanation of what your code does and how it answers the question. If you get a code snippet as an answer, you may not know what to do with it. Answer should give the OP and future visitors guidance on how to debug and fix their problem. Pointing out, what the idea behind your code is, greatly helps in understanding the issue and applying or modifying your solution.

Comment: @Palec (and any newcomers) it's a newish R feature called a pipe. Google for the R package `magrittr` which explains what it does pretty well - here's the link: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html.